# How can I use google.visualization typings with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use Google Charts in an Angular CLI (7.2.3) project but am running into an issue getting the typings to work.

First, I installed the typings with this command (both with and without the -dev flag):

> npm install --save-dev @types/google.visualization

After doing this, intellisense starts working immediately in Visual Studio Code and I don't get any highlighted errors when I create a simple test like this:

```
const chartBoxStyle: google.visualization.ChartBoxStyle = {};
```

However, when I try to build by running *ng build*, I get this error:

> error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.

I have tried adding this to my file with no luck:

```
declare const google: any;
```

My tsconfig.json file has the following for typeRoots and I see the google.visualization folder in there:

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of ideas on how to progress past this.

Comment: To create your project, did you run `ng new my-app`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Summary

The problem is the `"types"` property in the `./src/tsconfig.app.json` file.

Even though the root `./tsconfig.json` file sets `"typeRoots"` to `["node_modules/@types"]`, the `./src/tsconfig.app.json` file disables inclusion of those types by setting its own `types` property to an empty array.

### Solution

Open `./src/tsconfig.app.json` and make one of two changes:

- Delete the `"types": []"` property; that will tell the compiler to include all `typeRoots` packages.
- Alternatively, add the types that you want to use into the `"types": []"` array.

The latter option would look like this:

```
"types": [
  "google.visualization"
]
```

### Details

`ng build` reads its configuration from the `./angular.json` file.

That `./angular.json` file sets `"tsConfig"` to `"src/tsconfig.app.json"`.

That `./src/tsconfig.app.json` file sets its `"types"` property to an empty array.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []  <------------------------------- empty array
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

That's the problem, because as [the TypeScript documentation says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types): "If types is specified, only packages listed will be included."

Comment: Thank you for the help, it really was as simple as adding "google.visualization" to tsconfig.app.json. I'm quite surprised that intellisense works correctly without that set properly, but I'm please the fix was so simple.